# Sum and Substract column in same table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've the following table "TableOfDelivery" with 4 columns

[image]

I've worked out a SQL query (access 2016) to get the difference between **2** delivery week on **2** different reporting weeks:

```
SELECT TOP 2 
 t1.ref, t1.[delivery week], 
 (t2.qty-t1.qty) AS 
QtyDifferenceBetween2DeliveryWeekOn2DifferentWeekReporting
FROM 
  TableOfDelivery AS t1 INNER JOIN TableOfDelivery AS t2 ON (t1.ref = t2.ref) 
AND 
  (t1.[delivery week] = t2.[delivery week]  AND (t1.[reporting week] <> t2. 
[reporting week]) )
GROUP BY t1.[reporting week], t1.ref, t1.[delivery week], t2.qty-t1.qty
ORDER BY t1.[reporting week];
```

here is the outcomes from this SQL query:

[image]

The outcomes is ok only for delivery weeks that match. But I would like also to have the delivery weeks that do not match, see picture the lines highlighted in red and green.

[image]

For instance, for the red and green lines, I should have in the outcome query too:

[image]

Is there any away to do that?

Thank you very much

Comment: what is the difference between 30 for the week 41 and -50 for the week 43 ?

Comment: Please update your question to display your expected output.

Comment: Hello Andy, the 30 pcs on delivery week 2019-45 for the week reporting 2018-41 does not exist on week reporting 2018-37. So , it's 30-0=30.
For the 50pcs, thé 50 pcs on delivery week 2019-43 for the week reporting 2018-37 does not exist on week reporting 2018-41.So, it's 0-50=-50

Comment: @Arte first thing , first , we are to help with existing material. Can you provide us with what you have done, pls?

Comment: Hello @AndyK, Thanks. I've updated may post with material. I should have done it earlier. to be more clear about the outcomes. Thanks for your help

Comment: @AndyK, hello. based on your help, I translated your query on access one, it's running, but I'm closed to the result. Thanks

Comment: good to be able to help. accepting the answer or upvoting the answer is a way to say thanks too @Arte. Cheers for your feedback.

Comment: @AndyK, your help got me clother to the outcome I want, but it remains some discrpencies (I updated the post); Could you please have a look? It's at the beginning of the post

Comment: @Arte if I help you with your first question, then it should be considered answered. If there are discrepancies, please raise another question as it is another topic. Do not update the initial question with an additional question as it was WIP, this is very contrary to the SO rules and rude. Ty.

Comment: @Andy K , hello . Andy you're right. The answer is right thank you very much. I upvoted.

Comment: @Arte feel free to raise another question though, where you will link this question to the next.

Comment: @AndyK hello, as per your advices I did, I created a new post and linked to this one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54480089/get-rid-off-double-and-calculation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a `CASE` to get what you want.

```
SELECT t1.ref,
       t1.[delivery week],
       (t2.qty-t1.qty) AS QtyDiff,
       t1.[delivery week],
       CASE
           WHEN t1.[reporting week] <> t1.[delivery week] THEN t1.qty *-1
           ELSE t1.qty
       END AS new_qty
FROM TableOfDelivery AS t1
INNER JOIN TableOfDelivery AS t2 ON (t1.ref = t2.ref)
AND (t1.[delivery week] = t2.[delivery week]
     AND (t1.[reporting week] <> t2. [reporting week]))
GROUP BY t1.[reporting week],
         t1.ref,
         t1.[delivery week], (t2.qty-t1.qty),t1.qty
ORDER BY t1.[reporting week];
```

The `CASE`checks if there is a difference between the delivery week and the reporting week. If it is the case, it gives you the qty * -1.

I've tested it on postgres but not on msaccess as I do not have this db on my pc.

Comment: your help got me clother to the outcome I want, but it remains some discrpencies (I updated the post); Could you please have a look? The update It's at the beginning of the post

Answer (score 0):

When I pivot the above data, it looks like this.  What kind of results do you need.  Please show us.

```
            Deliv.Week-->               
Rptg.Week V                 
Sum of  qty Column Labels               
Row Labels  2019-35 2019-41 2019-43 2019-45 Grand Total
2018-37     20      30      50      30      130
2018-41     30                      30      60
Grand Total 50      30      50      60      190
```

Comment: Hello donPablo, this is the final outcome, but first, I need to work out a query in access calculate the grand total.

Comment: @Arte You NEED to show us YOUR requested output. We don't understand if certain figures need to be added/or/subtracted/or multiplied...

Comment: Hello donPablo, I modifiés m'y post with example. Thanks