# Get rid of duplicate record and calculated field

Tags: sql, ms-access

The post is linked to the following
[Sum and Substract column in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54425418/sum-and-substract-column-in-same-table)

I’ve the following table "TableOfDelivery" in access 2016

[image]

Based on stackflow team member help, I worked out a query

```
SELECT t1.ref, t1.[delivery week], (t2.qty-t1.qty) AS QtyDiff, iif(t1.[delivery week] <> t1.[delivery week],t1.qty *-1, t1.qty) AS Diff
FROM TableOfDelivery AS t1 LEFT JOIN TableOfDelivery AS t2 ON (t1.[delivery week] = t2.[delivery week]
AND (t1.[reporting week] <> t2.[reporting week])) AND (t1.ref = t2.ref)
GROUP BY t1.[reporting week], t1.ref, t1.[delivery week], (t2.qty-t1.qty), t1.qty
ORDER BY t1.[reporting week];
```

[image]

This is close to my final outcome but I would like to have this result:
Only 3 columns (see bold box)
Get rid off the duplicate ref/delivery combination (see crossed lines)

[image]

I would very appreciate your help.

I précised the calculation rules:
[image]

Comment: which 3 columns do you want? Plus why the delivery week with negative QtyDiff matter more?

Comment: You want to select records with a unique delivery week? Am i correct?

Comment: @Kars yes you're right

Comment: @Andy K, ref, week  delivery and the calculation qty. The negative QtyDiff matter because a qty can appear or disappear depending on the reportorting week .

Comment: To get rid of duplicates you must first decide which of the duplicates you want to keep or if you should have duplicates in the first place or are the duplicates indication of a bug. Getting rid of the last column is easy, just delete the relevant section from `SELECT`.

Comment: As said @Arte, please learn how to correctly ask questions by reading [mcve]. Currently what you are doing is asking us to do your homework

Comment: @Arte pls accept Lee 's answer. It is a good way to say thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### EDIT

With the additional information you have now provided in your question, I would suggest the following SQL:

```sql
select 
    t0.ref, 
    t0.[delivery week], 
    nz(t3.q1,0) - nz(t6.q2,0) as QtyDiff
from
    (
        tableofdelivery t0
        left join
        (
             select 
                t1.ref, t1.[delivery week], sum(t1.qty) as q1
             from 
                tableofdelivery t1
             where 
                t1.[reporting week] = 
                (
                    select max(t2.[reporting week]) 
                    from tableofdelivery t2 
                    where t2.ref = t1.ref
                )
             group by 
                t1.ref, t1.[delivery week]
        ) t3 on t0.ref = t3.ref and t0.[delivery week] = t3.[delivery week]
    ) left join
    (
        select 
            t4.ref, t4.[delivery week], sum(t4.qty) as q2
        from 
            tableofdelivery t4
        where 
            t4.[reporting week] < 
            (
                select max(t5.[reporting week]) 
                from tableofdelivery t5 
                where t5.ref = t4.ref
            )
        group by 
            t4.ref, t4.[delivery week]
    ) t6 on t0.ref = t6.ref and t0.[delivery week] = t6.[delivery week]
group by 
    t0.ref, t0.[delivery week], nz(t3.q1,0) - nz(t6.q2,0)
```

---

#### Original Answer

Assuming I've correctly understood the result that you are looking to obtain, I would suggest the following code:

```sql
select 
    t0.ref, 
    t0.[delivery week], 
    nz(t2.qty, 0) - t0.qty as qtydiff
from
    (
        tableofdelivery t0 inner join
        (
            select t.ref, t.[delivery week] as dw, min(t.[reporting week]) as rw
            from tableofdelivery t
            group by t.ref, t.[delivery week]
        ) t1 on 
        t0.ref = t1.ref and 
        t0.[delivery week]  = t1.dw and 
        t0.[reporting week] = t1.rw
    )
    left join tableofdelivery t2 on 
    t1.ref = t2.ref and 
    t1.dw = t2.[delivery week] and 
    t1.rw <> t2.[reporting week]
order by
    t0.ref, 
    t0.[delivery week]
```

Which, for your supplied sample data:

```
+----------------+---------------+---------------+-----+
| reporting week |      ref      | delivery week | qty |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+-----+
| 2018-37        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-31       |  19 |
| 2018-41        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-31       |  20 |
| 2018-37        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-33       |  50 |
| 2018-41        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-33       |  13 |
| 2018-37        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-35       |  50 |
| 2018-37        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-39       | 100 |
| 2018-41        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-43       |  13 |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+-----+
```

Yields the following result:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------+
|      ref      | delivery week | qtydiff |
+---------------+---------------+---------+
| DTR0000182433 | 2018-31       |       1 |
| DTR0000182433 | 2018-33       |     -37 |
| DTR0000182433 | 2018-35       |     -50 |
| DTR0000182433 | 2018-39       |    -100 |
| DTR0000182433 | 2018-43       |     -13 |
+---------------+---------------+---------+
```

Here, the innermost subquery first obtains the earliest `reporting week` record for each `delivery week` and `ref` combination. The `qty` associated with this minimum record is then subtracted from the `qty` associated with the other (non-minimum) records for the given `delivery week` and `ref` combination.

Alternatively, reversing the calculation based on your subsequent comments, you could try the following:

```sql
select 
    t0.ref, 
    t0.[delivery week], 
    t0.qty - nz(t2.qty, 0) as qtydiff
from
    (
        tableofdelivery t0 inner join
        (
            select t.ref, t.[delivery week] as dw, max(t.[reporting week]) as rw
            from tableofdelivery t
            group by t.ref, t.[delivery week]
        ) t1 on 
        t0.ref = t1.ref and 
        t0.[delivery week]  = t1.dw and 
        t0.[reporting week] = t1.rw
    )
    left join tableofdelivery t2 on 
    t1.ref = t2.ref and 
    t1.dw = t2.[delivery week] and 
    t1.rw > t2.[reporting week]
order by
    t0.ref, 
    t0.[delivery week]
```

Which, for your supplied sample data:

```
+----------------+---------------+---------------+-----+
| reporting week |      ref      | delivery week | qty |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+-----+
| 2018-37        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-31       |  19 |
| 2018-41        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-31       |  20 |
| 2018-37        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-33       |  50 |
| 2018-41        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-33       |  13 |
| 2018-37        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-35       |  50 |
| 2018-37        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-39       | 100 |
| 2018-41        | DTR0000182433 | 2018-43       |  13 |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+-----+
```

Yields the following result:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------+
|      ref      | delivery week | qtydiff |
+---------------+---------------+---------+
| DTR0000182433 | 2018-31       |       1 |
| DTR0000182433 | 2018-33       |     -37 |
| DTR0000182433 | 2018-35       |      50 |
| DTR0000182433 | 2018-39       |     100 |
| DTR0000182433 | 2018-43       |      13 |
+---------------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks Lee Mac, the outcome is almost what I want, the last line should be +13. There were no 13pcs on reporting week 2018-37 related to the delivey week 2018-43. The 13pcs only appears on reporting week 2018-41,   on  the delivey week 2018-43

Comment: @Arte Sorry, but I don't understand the logic of why delivery week `2018-43` should yield `+13` and not `-13`; if this is the case, shouldn't `2018-39` yield `+100` rather than `-100`?

Comment: first of all, thank you for your help.  You can notice that if you compare rw 2018-37 Vs 2018-41, the wd  2018-43  is only appearing on rw 2018-41, this means that +13 pcs popped up.  The calculation is right for  wd 2018-39 and 2018-35 because those pieces desappeared on rw 2018-41, so there are negative values. I would like to compare in term of dw qty, the latest week (rw 2018-41) vs the earliest week (rw 2018-37).

Comment: @Arte I have updated my answer above. I'm afraid I still don't understand how/why the records for delivery weeks `2018-35` & `2018-39` should be handled differently to delivery week `2018-43`...

Comment: I've précised via picture (end of the post) the calculation rules, could you plz check?. That's my mistake, I should make myself clear.

Comment: @Arte Thank you for providing the additional information. I have updated my answer above (refer to the first section of the answer). This is probably not the most elegant way to write the code, but I have run out of time to work on this.

Comment: @leemac I think you overhelp here. Op wants someone to do his homework, which is not the aim of the site. My 2 cents 

Comment: @AndyK You're probably right... I just can't resist a coding challenge.

Comment: Me too @LeeMac but we need also to set the correct example, otherwise newcomers will say that SO is not a welcoming place. It is welcoming , as long we all have a common understanding of the rules  

Comment: @AndyK, hello Andy, thank you for your help too. I'm 41 years old, try to solve this issue for 2 weeks everyday. I provided some material too in order to be considered as a studend ;-) Any I'll study closely what you did, because it's high level. I hope to do the sae too

Comment: @arte your age is not relevant here. The aim of SO is to get things spot on, to have the most efficient help possible. That you are 20, 40 or 60, as long as you learn and you use StackOverflow, you should follow the rules. But ok, I give you some slack, no worries. Just an honest reminder for your next question, especially as you are 40 therefore you should set the example 

Comment: @AndyK I agree and can see how a question such as this could lead others who are new to the site to incorrectly believe that SO is a place where members will happily write your code for you. Of course, many other answers on this site will also provide a complete solution for the OP, though, with far fewer lines of code involved, it doesn't seem as much like "work".

Comment: @Arte If the answer I have provided has sufficiently answered your question, please mark my answer as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate) so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site.

Comment: @Lee Mac, I upvoted, how I set the question answered?

Comment: @Arte By clicking the tick symbol beneath the up & down vote arrows - for more information, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Lee Mac, I did it as agreed.

Answer (score 0):

First, build your first query as a way to filter the minimal quantity difference (qtydiff). For reading clarity, I've used `TableOfDelivery` to summarize the inital query, the one you've put above. You will need to replace `TableOfDelivery` with your query, to make it work.

> Query 1

I've put `deliveryweek`, instead of `[Delivery Week]`. You will need to change it back to `[Delivery Week]`. I did it as it was easier for me, for testing purpose.

```
    SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableOfDelivery AS  a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT deliveryweek, MIN(qtydiff) AS "min_qty_diff"      
      FROM TableOfDelivery 
        GROUP BY deliveryweek
    ) AS b
        ON a.deliveryweek = b.deliveryweek
        AND a.qtydiff  = b.min_qty_diff
```

However, as first filter, you need to make also sure that the difference (diff) is also minimal as there maybe equal differences. Put the query above (Query 1) into a subquery

```
SELECT 
 sub_query.ref,
 sub_query.deliveryweek,
 sub_query.qtydiff,
 MIN(sub_query.diff)
FROM 
(the query above) AS sub_query
GROUP BY 
    sub_query.ref,
    sub_query.deliveryweek,
    sub_query.qtydiff
```

Which gives you the final result

```
    SELECT 
    sub_query.ref,
    sub_query.deliveryweek,
    sub_query.qtydiff,
    MIN(sub_query.diff)
FROM 
(
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableOfDelivery AS  a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT deliveryweek, MIN(qtydiff) AS "min_qty_diff"
      --, MIN(diff) AS "min_diff"       
      FROM TableOfDelivery 
        GROUP BY deliveryweek
    ) AS b
        ON a.deliveryweek = b.deliveryweek
        AND a.qtydiff  = b.min_qty_diff
) as sub_query
GROUP BY 
    sub_query.ref,
    sub_query.deliveryweek,
    sub_query.qtydiff
;
```

[SQL Fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gXM95P3zXSgBE3x7KN4Su9/0)

Comment: thanks. I tried to run the query, but I got an error. I think is due to the TableOfDelivery that you told me to replace somewhere. Could you please clarify?